# Difficulty Positioning Elements in CSS with position absolute & relative

Tags: html, css, icons, css-position, font-awesome

I'm currently working on a project where I'm trying to adjust the positioning of elements within a sidebar. The sidebar contains Font Awesome icons and corresponding text elements, and I'm attempting to move both the icons together as one entity using an attribute selector and doing the same but with a class selector with my text within the sidebar.

I've applied the following HTML and CSS code to target the icons and text elements:

HTML

```
<li> <a href= "#"> <i class="fas fa-search "></i> <span class="nav-color move-text">Search</span> </a> </li>
   <li> <a href= "#"> <i class="fa-solid fa-gears "></i><span class="nav-color move-text">Settings</span> </a> </li>
   <li> <a href= "#"> <i class="fa-solid fa-inbox "></i><span class="nav-color move-text">Updates</span> </a> </li>
```

CSS

```
[class*="fa-"] {
position:relative;
top:auto;
left:15px;
bottom:20px;
right:auto;
color:#a5a8a8
}

.move-text{
position:relative;
left:15px;


}
```

Despite applying the left property to the move-text class, the text elements are not moving as expected. The icons are behaving incorrectly when I use position: absolute or position relative

when I use position relative for both icons

[image]

when i use position relative for icon and absolute for text
[image]

when i use position absolute for both

[image]

when i use position absolute for icon and relative for text
[image]

The main issue is the icons and text not moving I may be able to move it initially at first by changing it from position absolute to position relative which will make the text go to the other end of the page and vice versa but if I was to try to adjust it after that like adjust any of the top,bottom,left,right values it would not move at all it's like it's not being recognised.

To add to that also, excluding the position absolute/relative if I were to adjust any of the top bottom , left, right say I put right at 15px; launch my live web server and see that it loads and works then adjust it with the other values again it won't move any subsequent attempts to fine-tune the positioning by adjusting other values yield no results. It's as if the elements are stuck in their initial positions regardless of the changes I make to the CSS properties.

The main issue is the icons and text not moving I may be able to move it initially at first by changing it from position absolute to position relative which will make the text go to the other end of the page and vice versa but if I was to try to adjust it after that like adjust any of the top,bottom,left,right values it would not move at all it's like it's not being recognised.

To add to that also, excluding the position absolute/relative if I were to adjust any of the top bottom , left, right say I put right at 15px; launch my live web server and see that it loads and works then adjust it with the other values again it won't move any subsequent attempts to fine-tune the positioning by adjusting other values yield no results. It's as if the elements are stuck in their initial positions regardless of the changes I make to the CSS properties.

I have ensured

1.There are no console erros

2.No inline elements tampering with they way they're appearing

3.As far as I know the syntax is correct feel free to spot any mistakes that I can't see

Has anyone encountered this issue? I greatly appreciate any insights or form of help thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstand the concept of relative and absolute positioning in css. By giving a block position: relative, you define a reference point for absolutely positioned elements nested within it. If position relative is not specified on the immediate parent, you need to look for it on a higher element in the hierarchy. If no element is given position relative, then the body element will be the exact reference for Position absolute.

In the code below, the 4 child elements are positioned absolutely. But two of them have a parent that is given position: relative, while the other two do not.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 2;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.parent-relative {
  width: 24em;
  height: 16em;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
}

.child1 {
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 2em;
  top: 2em;
  color: white;
  max-width: 150px;
  font-size: 70%;
}

.child2 {
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2em;
  right: 2em;
  max-width: 150px;
  font-size: 70%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Relative/absolute concept</h1>
<div class="parent-relative">
  <div class="child1">My name is Child1. My parent is green DIV with position relative</div>
  <div class="child2">My name is Child2. My parent is green DIV with position relative</div>
</div>

<div class="parent-no-relative">
  <div class="child1">My name is Child1. I don't have a parent relative. My position is calculated from the BODY</div>
  <div class="child2">My name is Child2. I don't have a parent relative. My position is calculated from the BODY</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the late reply I have actually been struggling to understand position absolute and relative or have only understood small aspects of it by just doing asking chatgpt to give me a base understanding -the course I did didn't cover it all but I think this will help thank you!!!!

Comment: So for more clarity before I fix my code do I need to give my position absolute/relative a parent relative so it positions correctly? If so how do I do that does it just need to put it inside a div element and then position it afterwards?

Comment: And I don't necessarily understand this part either (By giving a block position: relative, you define a reference point for absolutely positioned elements nested within it)

Comment: Look at the code for the `.parent-relative` block (it's the green DIV). It contains blocks `.child1` and `.child2`. Without the `position relative` property of the green block, the position of its descendants would be calculated not from the green part, but from the body.


Looking at your code, I would basically not use positioning for it, but use something like `display: flex`

Comment: I have watched a flexbox grid tutorial because I didn't know what it was or how to apply it to my code and I don't see how to apply it to my code apart from the centering property if I'm not mistaken the primary purpose of flexbox is that the icons grow /shrink according to the user adjusting the browser  but that's not exactly what I'm trying to achieve is there something I'm missing ?

Comment: @Your-neigbourhood-developer You have a block with an image and text inside. With flexbox, you can align images and text within a block without having to position them.

Comment: oh I see thank you this is very helpful! I'm gonna figure out how to do that thank you!

Comment: Fodorov I have used the flexbox property flex direction column and its  working to position my icons and text as one entity it's good but the problem is the icons are mis-aligned and I need to just move them slightly down but it's the container that moves not the icons of course after I move the container is there a way for me to move the icons seperately? I only need to move them ever so slightly

Comment: Also when I use align:left it pushes it back but not enough for the text search,setting,updates to align with the the below text (there are icons which are behind the text search,setting,updates) the rest is not within the same container is there a styling property will can push it farther back?

Comment: Without seeing the code, it's hard to imagine what's going on there. But I can assume that your icons have different widths. There are several options to resolve this issue. For example, you can use the `min-width` property for icons. Another option is the `flex-basis` property. The wrong way is to try to somehow adjust the positions manually, using `padding` / `margin`, `transform: translate`, etc. You don’t need to replace the browser’s work with your calculations; let it do the math itself.